# Cannot set session variables from child process callbacks

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have a node/express application which calls an external program and needs to capture output and handle different possible states.

The problem is: I can't set the session state inside the on(data) callback.

The function handling the call is:

```
app.get('/test/:script', function(req, res) {
   if (req.session.state != SessionState.STARTED) {
      req.session.state = SessionState.STARTED;
      req.session.scriptname = req.params.script;
      req.session.outputText = '';

      var test = spawn('./Test', [ req.session.scriptname ]);

      test.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log('+++' + JSON.stringify(req.session)); req.session.outputText += data.toString() + '<br/>'; });
      test.on('close', function(code) { console.log('---' + JSON.stringify(req.session)); console.log(code); req.session.state = SessionState.FINISHED; });
   }

   res.redirect(301, '/');
})
```

And the default route is:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   var responseBody = '';
   var responseHead = '';
   switch (req.session.state) {
      case undefined:
      case SessionState.IDLE:
         var files = fs.readdirSync('../input')
         for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var fname = files[i];
            responseBody += '<a href="/test/' + fname + '">' + fname + '</a> <br/>';
         }
         req.session.state = SessionState.IDLE;
         break;

      case SessionState.STARTED:
         responseHead += '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">';
         responseBody += req.session.outputText;
         console.log('***' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
         break;

      case SessionState.FINISHED:
         responseBody += 'Execution finished';
         break;
   }

   var responseText = '<html>' +
      '<head>' + responseHead + '</head>' +
      '<body>' + responseBody + '</body>' +
      '</html>'

   res.send(responseText);
})
```

The console log shows completely different objects: one is updated by the first function and contains the full output of my program, but the other object (logged by the second function) never changes.

How do I make sure I am always accessing the same session object? If I add req.sessionID to the console output, the value is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which console.logs you mean (there's a few there), but one potential cause of your problems is that the redirect is being issued before the child process has finished.

Here's a possible rewrite:

```
app.get('/test/:script', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.state != SessionState.STARTED) {
    req.session.state = SessionState.STARTED;
    req.session.scriptname = req.params.script;
    req.session.outputText = '';

    var test = spawn('./Test', [ req.session.scriptname ]);

    test.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
      console.log('+++' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
      req.session.outputText += data.toString() + '<br/>';
    });
    test.on('close', function(code) { 
      console.log('---' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
      console.log(code); 
      req.session.state = SessionState.FINISHED;
      res.redirect(301, '/');
    });
  } else {
   res.redirect(301, '/');
  }
})
```

Comment: The process runs for some time, and I would like to have a process polling for partial results.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I think that the default for `express-session` is that sessions are saved at the end of a response, which in your case will be the redirect. If you want to implement polling, you need to prevent the session from being saved automatically. I'm not really sure how to do that, though :(